# I use traceView and i see android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage 76.4%

Tags: android

I use traceView and i see android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage 76.4%
What does this mean?
and how to find  where is this bug in my source?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is probably OK. This value shows how much cpu takes the whole rendering process (so traverse by all views to find views to invaliade, call View.draw() and View.onDraw() methods, lock/unlock the canvas). Probably most of this 76% it's your code, so you should start to check time spend by your classes.